# How to get tableView instance from Custom UITableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having a tableView with Custom UITableViewCell and in that cell class I want to access the tableView which is holding it. For this purpose I am using cell.superView which is returning as nil. But the same is working fine when I am not using any custom UITableViewCell.

Here is my code,

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? TestTableViewCell
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "Test"
    return cell!
}

class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

func loadDetails() {
    let tableView = self.superview //which is returning nil here
}}
```

Comment: A cell shouldn't need to access the table view. There is likely a much better solution but you need to update your question clearly explaining what you are attempting to do.

Comment: That's probably a bad idea.  You should rethink your design.  What is it that you need from the tableView that you can't pass as parameter to your cell?

Comment: why do you want your cell to have access to the tableView presenting that ?

Comment: BTW you already have access to the tableView in the tableview (Cell for row at ) function

Comment: Aside from everything else, you shouldn't assume the tableView is the superview oft the cell.  If anything, it's some ancestor up the chain.

Answer (score 0):

On `UITableViewDelegate`, when a cell is tapped, you can know which `UITableView` holds it.

The triggered method is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // tableView is the UITableView holding the cell.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have told you in the comments, it is not a good idea that the cell can access properties of the tableView, because the cell is dependent of the table. That means, that if you grant power to the cell to be able to change properties in the tableView, then both are dependent and it could be a mess with hundreds of cells changing properties in the table. So, it is a good idea to rethinking the design (i.e. protocols oriented programming).

But if there is not another viable way, then you can add a `private weak var` (we need it **private** to ensure only the cell can access it, and **weak** beacause we do not want a retain cycle):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! TestTableViewCell
    cell.tableView = tableView
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Test"
    return cell
}

class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    private weak var tableView: UITableView?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func loadDetails() {
        guard let tableView = tableView else { return }
        // Here you can access your tableView
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not do this. A cell should not be told about its table view. Until the OP returns and provides more details about what they are trying to do, posting any answer is just guess work. But no matter what, adding a table view property to the cell is wrong. There is a reason Apple doesn't already provide such a property.

Comment: I do not consider it is wrong, only is a simple/bad design. I mean, maybe a button inside the cell wants to tell the tableView to scroll to the bottom and it call it directly. That is only a shortcut that works in a simple project but not in a bigger one. It is not a good practice but it is a workaround if someone is learning or exploring possibilities. But as @rmaddy said: "Do not do this."